# Is there any alternative location to download IEDriverServer binary for Selenium

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

The links at https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ appear broken, and the other location I found

http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

is put in the blockedlist.

Does anyone have alternative please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative location to download *IEDriverServer* is: [IE WebDriver Tool for Internet Explorer 11](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44069)

---

### Update

So now we have a official confirmation, there are **no** other alternatives to download *IEDriverServer*.

Comment: The linked component is the long-deprecated Microsoft IE implementation for WebDriver. It was abandoned before being completed, and is not supported in any way. When downloading this, you will not receive a copy of `IEDriverServer.exe`

Comment: @JimEvans thank you for the answer! So IE is completely out of the picture?

Comment: @Heinz Not at all. Just that Microsoft’s driver for IE is not complete, and never will be. They abandoned their IE implementation in favor of their Edge implementation. The Selenium project’s IE driver is still under active development. This is the driver you’re attempting to download but is blocked for you for reasons I do not understand.